# Turning rmarkdown section into image

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr

I have a couple of rmarkdown-sections, only a couple of lines each intermingling text, markup and code-chunks, that I would like to turn into an *image*.

I haven't found a good solution yet. Maybe I need to accept pdf-output for now and postprocess? Anyone has a better idea?

This would be an example of rmarkdown-code, which I would like to transform into an image.

````
## Question 2
Please compute the *pearson correlation* between
`mtcars$mpg` and `mtcars$disp` and round it to two digits.

### Answer
```{r}
round(cor(mtcars$mpg, mtcars$disp), 2)
```
````

PS: I look for sth like https://github.com/yonicd/carbonate, but for rendered rmarkdown instead of source code. Ideally I would have most of the options for syntax highlighting and controlling the output of the rmarkdown document.

Comment: I think it would help to provide a reproducible question here. For instance, are these sections part of a whole document, or are you interested solely in converting what could be a solitary/whole rmarkdown document into an image vice a normal rendering output? Since pandoc doesn't support image outputs, you'll likely need to render an intermediate format (html or pdf come to mind) and then post-process that output with ghostscript or similar.

Comment: Interesting question. I have tried to play around with the `carbonate` package and with [Carbon](https://carbon.now.sh/) directly but that did not work well for me. As a workaround you may create HTML output (HTML has no page breaks as PDF does) and capture screenshots of the relevant parts with an appropriate tool, e.g. `greenshot` on Windows.

Comment: Thank you. :)
Ideally I would looking for an automated solution, so a scriptable postprocessing would be ideal.

Comment: A combination of `rmarkdown::render(..., "pdf_document"))` followed by `pdftools::pdf_convert` looks very promising right now.